# Serverless create snspolicy fails with invalid parameter

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sns, serverless

Here is the error.

```
An error occurred: SNSTopicPolicy - Invalid parameter:
Policy Error: null (Service: AmazonSNS; 
Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidParameter; 
Request ID: 38a567df-2cff-50bf-8f0e-33a91775cc6e).
```

I cannot find a place to look into logs to tell me what parameter is missing.?.?  I'm pretty sure I have everything that is required.  I'm using this [site](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sns-sqs-as-subscriber.html) and their api pages.

```
SNSTopic:
  Type: AWS::SNS::Topic
  Properties:
    DisplayName: Aura main Topic
    TopicName: ${file(./env.yml):${opt:stage, self:provider.stage}.env.auraSnsTopicName}

SNSTopicPolicy:
  Type: AWS::SNS::TopicPolicy
  Properties:
    PolicyDocument:
      Id: auraAllowSQSsendrobelrobel
      Statement:
        -
          Effect: Allow
          Action:
            - sns: Publish
          Resource: { "Fn::GetAtt":["SQSQueue" ,"Arn"]}
          Principle:
            AWS: "*"
    Topics:
      - { "Ref": "SNSTopic" }


SQSQueue:
  Type: AWS::SQS::Queue
  Properties:
    QueueName: ${file(./env.yml):${opt:stage, self:provider.stage}.env.eeegPagesQueueName}
    RedrivePolicy:
      deadLetterTargetArn: {"Fn::GetAtt" : [ "SQSQueueDLQ", "Arn" ]}
      maxReceiveCount: 2


SQSQueuePolicy:
  Type: AWS::SQS::QueuePolicy
  Properties:
    PolicyDocument:
      Id: allowSNSSourceAndLambdaTrigger
      Statement:
        -
          Effect: Allow
          Action:
            - SQS:ReceiveMessage
            - SQS:SendMessage
            - SQS:ChangeMessageVisibility
            - SQS:ListDeadLetterSourceQueues
            - SQS:GetQueueUrl
            # - lambda:CreateEventSourceMapping
            # - lambda:ListEventSourceMappings
            # - lambda:ListFunction
          Resource: {"Ref": "SNSTopic"}
    Queues:
      - { "Ref": "SQSQueue" }
```

I have an SQS Policy statement that is working just fine.

```
  Your Environment Information ----------------------------
     OS:                    Mac darwin
     Node Version:           8.12.0
     Serverless Version:     1.32.0
```

Comment: it might be the wrong indentation  you have there, check this article (the yaml part) and ident accordingly: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/quickref-iam.html#scenario-sns-policy

Comment: Thanks @alexk Indentation is fine.  I'm using Serverless and this was a subset of the whole doc.

Comment: Cool, glad you got your answer. I have encountered problem with copying files from Windows to Linux and indentation got messed up hence my guess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out you need spelling is important and also the AWS sub object was not needed.
`Principal: "*"`

Working Policy below:

```
SNSTopicPolicy:
  Type: AWS::SNS::TopicPolicy
  Properties:
    PolicyDocument:
      Statement:
        - Sid: auraAllowSQSPublish
          Effect: Allow
          Principal: "*"
          Action: "sns:Publish"
          Resource:  { "Ref": "SNSTopic" }
    Topics:
      - { "Ref": "SNSTopic" }
```